# Flutter - Textfield not showing up when keyboard appears on android

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, textfield

My problem is that when I focus on the textfield, the keyboard appears but the layout doesn't resize to keep it in the view. This problem is only with android and not iOS: Here a screenshot of what I mean:

Before and after on android:

[image: Before]  [image: After]

Before and after on iOS:

[image]  [image]

Here is my class :

```dart
class PlayerSelectionPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int itemCount = Provider.of<PlayerProvider>(context).getPlayerList.length;
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('player_selection_page_title')),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(), settings: RouteSettings(name: 'Home page')));
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.chevron_right,
          size: 30,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      body: itemCount > 0 ? ListView.builder(
          itemCount: itemCount,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                PlayerDismissible(index),
                Divider(
                  height: 0,
                )
              ],
            );
          }) : Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('player_selection_page_empty_text'), textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2)
      ),
      bottomSheet: BottomPlayerBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my BottomPlayerBar() :

```dart
class BottomPlayerBar extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _BottomPlayerBarState createState() => _BottomPlayerBarState();
}

class _BottomPlayerBarState extends State<BottomPlayerBar> {
  String playerName;
  FocusNode myFocusNode;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myFocusNode = FocusNode();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (ModalRoute.of(context).isCurrent) {
        myFocusNode.requestFocus();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 80, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 25, left: 20, right: 70),
        child: TextField(
          focusNode: myFocusNode,
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
          onChanged: (val) => playerName = val.trim(),
          onSubmitted: (val) {
            if (playerName != null && playerName != '') {
              Provider.of<PlayerProvider>(context, listen: false).addPlayer(playerName);
              HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
              myFocusNode.requestFocus();
            } else {
              myFocusNode.unfocus();
            }
          },
          maxLength: 19,
          autocorrect: false,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
              counterText: "",
              border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  const Radius.circular(30.0),
                ),
              ),
              filled: true,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 20),
              hintStyle: GoogleFonts.rubik(color: Colors.grey[500], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('player_selection_page_hint'),
              fillColor: Colors.white),
        )
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    myFocusNode.dispose();
  }
}
```

Here is my android manifest:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myApp">
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="myApp !"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.LaunchTheme"
              android:resource="@style/LaunchTheme"
              />
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post the setup in the android manifest file

Comment: Here it is, but I don't really know how it'll help.

Comment: Because of your 'android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"'. It should be doing what you want.

Comment: Should I delete this line ?

Comment: It didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml
```

For me changing below item property from true to false

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
```

I had this issue, too. This line was added as a result of using the flutter_native_splash package.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was exactly the problem !

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap your BottomPlayerBar widget with the Transform Widget as shown below.

```
Transform.translate(
    offset: Offset(0.0, -1 * MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
    child: BottomPlayerBar(),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Resizing the page when the soft keyboard appears is handled through the `android:windowSoftInputMode` activity parameter in AndroidManifest. See the [official documnetation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

If you have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your AndroidManifest.xml, the textfield will automatically reposition when the softkeyboard appears. **The same behaviour will not happen if the parameter is not there in `AndroidManifest.xml`**

Could you recheck this by modifying your AndroidManifest. That will also explain why it is not working only in Android but works in iOS (Because iOS handles this implicitly)

**P.S:** When modifying the AndoridManifest.xml, hot reload may not work. You will need an actual stop and start running the app.

Answer (score 1):

Use margin for your **BottomPlayerBar** widget:

```
margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add isScrollControlled = true to showModalBottomSheet it'll allow the bottom sheet to take the full required height which gives more insurance that TextField is not covered by the keyboard.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25.0))),
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (context) => Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:18 ),
      child: BottomPlayerBar(),
          ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

So that's why I don't usually try to use `Scaffold` build in parameters. To save time on resolving platform dependent issues I would go with using simple `Widgets` to achieve result you want.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[

              // YOU BODY VIEW 85 HEIGHT %
              ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85,
                ),
                child: MainWidget()
              ),

              // YOUR BOTTOM VIEW 15 %
              ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15,
                ),
                child: BottomPlayerBar()
              ),
            ],
        ),
    ),
  );
}
```

For your example above `PlayerSelectionPage`.

```
class PlayerSelectionPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int itemCount = Provider.of<PlayerProvider>(context).getPlayerList.length;
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('player_selection_page_title')),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(), settings: RouteSettings(name: 'Home page')));
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.chevron_right,
          size: 30,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[

                // NEW VIEW
                ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.85,
                ),
              child: itemCount > 0 ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: itemCount,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        PlayerDismissible(index),
                        Divider(
                          height: 0,
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  }) : Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('player_selection_page_empty_text'), textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2)
              ),
            ),

                // NEW VIEW
                ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15,
                  ),
                  child: BottomPlayerBar()
                ),
              ],
          ),
      ),
      body: itemCount > 0 ? ListView.builder(
          itemCount: itemCount,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                PlayerDismissible(index),
                Divider(
                  height: 0,
                )
              ],
            );
          }) : Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('player_selection_page_empty_text'), textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be to use the bottom padding for you BottomPlayerBar,

Instead of,

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 25, left: 20, right: 70),
```

Try,

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 25 + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom, left: 20, right: 70),
```

Here we are just adding any padding added to the bottom of the scaffold from

```
MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `stack` like this :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: null),
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 100,
              child: TextField(),
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the app comments for me, I added a statefulBuilder, so the bottom sheet gets informed of the padding changes

```dart
  showModalBottomSheet(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
      elevation: 0.0,
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (_) {
        return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, StateSetter stateSetter) {
          return Padding(
            padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextField(),
                TextField(),
                TextField(),
                TextField(),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
      },
    );
```